# Parse solr response in php and show them in a html table

Tags: php, html, xml, solr

So I have many solr instances running and to submit a search I just put a quick website together. After I make the request URL, in php I use the following to get the XML response back from solr:

```
    $solr_return= file_get_contents($full_request_URL);
```

Now the response is not in a simple xml format and it has solr-ness to it if you know what I mean. I want to be able to parse the returned xml and show them in rows in a table in html.

I've been looking online and there are many different ideas that make me think maybe I'm  totally off and this is not the way to do it. How would you do this if you were me?

The xml in `$solr_return` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">95</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="indent">true</str>
    <str name="rows">10</str>
    <str name="start">0</str>
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="shards">some shards here</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="2403043" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="1">test1</str>
    <str name="2">test2</str>
    <str name="3">test3</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="1">test1</str>
    <str name="2">test2</str>
    <str name="3">test3</str>
  </doc>
</result>
</response>
```

For this example, I want to show a table with three columns of 1, 2, and 3 and two rows of test1, test2, and test3.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to add `&wt=php` to the Solr request URL, and then run `eval()` and assign the results to an array (assuming you trust your Solr server not to send malicious code back). Then the Solr results will just be in a regular PHP array and you can manipulate it as you need.

Alternatively you can add `&wt=json` at the end, get the results in JSON format and then run `json_decode()` on the returned string in PHP to convert it to a PHP array.

Comment: Sweetness! Thank you for this answer. I knew there should be an easier way but sometimes you don't know what to search for! I added `&wt=php` and I got excited to see the result. I'm going to have fun with it for a while... ;)

Comment: I'd suggest using JSON as well...avoid those nasty `eval` calls, especially with data coming back from elsewhere (even though it's solr and probably safe).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$solr_return = file_get_contents($full_request_URL);
$solr_return = simplexml_load_string($solr_return);
$xpath = $solr_return->xpath( '//result/doc' );

$rowCols = array();
if( count( $xpath ) > 0 ) {
    foreach( $xpath as $key => $value ) {
        if( !isset ( $rowCols[ $key ] ) ) {
            $rowCols[ $key ] = '<tr>';
        }

        foreach( $value as $k => $v ) {
            $rowCols[ $key ] .= '<td>' . $v . '</td>';
        }

        $rowCols[ $key ] .= '</tr>';
    }
}     else {
    $rowCols[] = '<tr><td colspan="3"></td></tr>'
    }
$rowCols = implode( '', $rowCols);
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table border="0" width="50%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing-="3">
<tbody>
<?php echo $rowCols;?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and thank you for the details on how to create the table. Can you explain the line `xpath = $solr_return->xpath( '//result/doc' );
` what object '$solr_return` needs to be? I get this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object`

Comment: Check the value in `$solr_return`. If it is an XML string, then do a `simplexml_load_string` on it. I've modified my response to reflect the same. Please check again.